# What is the appropriate scope for replying to comments via Youtube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently able to reply to comments on Youtube using the "youtube.force-ssl" scope Youtube Data API v3.

However, that scope also grants permission to many things that are irrelevant to me (such as deleting videos) and I'd prefer to use a more minimal scope, if possible.

I've been trying to understand if I could use the more minimal "youtube" scope.
What confuses me is that I'm getting 403 ("PERMISSION_DENIED") when I try to use this scope, but on the user-facing description it says it is used to "View and manage your YouTube activity, including posting public comments".

My questions are:

1. Is it indeed impossible to use the "youtube" scope for replying to comments?
2. Are there any other alternative to the "youtube.force-ssl" scope for replying to comments?

Thank you!

Comment: please edit your question and include your code, if you are getting an error we need to see the code assocated with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official specifications, there's only one scope available for you to use:

> [**Authorization**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert#auth)
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).
>
> **Scope**
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`

Even if, for some reason, the current API implementation would accept as valid a call to the [`Comments.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) API endpoint using the other scope -- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` --, I'd recommend against such a practice. API users should always rely on documented behavior when using various endpoints.